# Why Copy function behaves differently in 64-bit Delphi XE3?

Tags: delphi, copy, delphi-xe3

In Delphi XE3, the *Copy* function can be used for string type with or without the third parameter. For example,

```
s := '1234567890';
Writeln(Copy(s, 2));
```

The above prints 234567890 if compiled for 32-bit EXE. However when the same code compiles to 64-bit EXE, it will print nothing.

Why is this? I have to actually change all such code to e.g. *Copy(s, 2, Length(s) - 1)* when porting 32-bit app to 64-bit.

Comment: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=113805

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could not reproduced the behaviour you report. When I compiled that code in a fully updated 64 bit XE3, the code produced the expected output.

I conclude that either:

1. You have not fully updated your XE3 installation.
2. Your code is using a different `Copy` function that is contained in your code.

Thanks to @bummi for pointing out the [QC report](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=113805) that proves that item 1 is the explanation. Your solution is (obviously) to apply the updates.